# How to update a table based on criteria from that same table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

[image: UPDATE_2ndStudentRecordInSameTable]

In the image above you'll note the first 6 rows that shows 2 records for each StudentID.  I am needing to UPDATE, for each group of StudentID's, the EndDate column value of the 2nd record with a value of ONE DAY LESS THAN the StatusEffectiveDate of the first record for the same StudentID.  I am working with SQL Server 2014.

So the first record should look like:

[image: HowResultsShouldLook]

Here is my SQL code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM #TEMP_99RecordsNeedingEndDateUpdated 
ORDER BY StudentID asc, StatusEffectiveDate desc
```

Any help/direction would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you recognize which of these two rows is the second?

Comment: Sorry for leaving that out.  The StatusEffectiveDate of the 2nd record is LESSER than the first record listed for the same StudentID.  Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: So to be clear, you'd want to update the the table to have something like `EndDate` column = `DATEADD(DAY, -1, LAG(StatusEffectiveDate) OVER (PARTITION BY StudentID ORDER BY StatusEffectiveDate DESC)` where a previous row exists? Do two rows always exist or can there be more with differing end dates?

Comment: Correct on the formula for the END DATE.  There is always 2 rows.  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Thank you all for all your suggestions.  I will be trying each one.  Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Using what ZLK stated with a CTE to update the rows.

```
;WITH cte AS
(SELECT 
    * 
  , DATEADD(DAY, -1, LAG(statuseffectivedate) OVER (PARTITION BY StudentID ORDER BY statuseffectivedate DESC)) AS NewDate
FROM #TEMP_99RecordsNeedingEndDateUpdated)

UPDATE cte
SET cte.enddate = cte.NewDate
WHERE cte.NewDate IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and time. I will try this example.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but here's one to try as well:

```sql
BEGIN TRANSACTION
UPDATE [YourTable] SET EndDate = DATEADD(DAY, -1, t.MaxDate)
FROM  
(  
    SELECT StudentID, MAX(StatusEffectiveDate) as MaxDate
    FROM [YourTable]
    GROUP BY StudentID
) t  
WHERE [YourTable].StudentID = t.StudentID AND [YourTable].StatusEffectiveDate <> t.MaxDate

-- COMMIT TRANSACTION
-- ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

As others have stated, this has very limited constraints on your data.

Essentially, I'm updating the EndDate to a new value, based on a sub query for the MAX() date from the same student ID. Finally, to avoid updating all student records, I ensure that the StatusEffectiveDate is not the later date.

Comment: Thanks for your time.   I will try this as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as 
( select *  
       , row_number over (partition by studentID order by StatusEffectiveDate desc ) as rnD
       , row_number over (partition by studentID order by StatusEffectiveDate asc  ) as rnA
  from table t 
)

select cte.StudentID, cte.Location, cte.Status, cte.EconDisCode, cte.StatusEffectiveDate  
     , cte.EndDate
from cte 
where rnD == 1 
union 
select cteA.StudentID, cteA.Location, cteA.Status, cteA.EconDisCode, cteA.StatusEffectiveDate
     , dateadd(d, -1, cteD.StatusEffectiveDate) 
from cte cteA  
join cte cteD
  on cteA.StudentID = cteD.StudentID 
 and cteA.rnD = 1 
 and cteD.rnA = 1
order by studentID, StatusEffectiveDate desc 


update cteA
set cteA.EndDate = dateadd(d, -1, cteD.StatusEffectiveDate) 
from cte cteA  
join cte cteD
  on cteA.StudentID = cteD.StudentID 
 and cteA.rnD = 1 
 and cteD.rnA = 1
order by studentID, StatusEffectiveDate desc
```

Include actual text (not image) so can cut and paste

Answer (score 0):

This has very limited constraints, notably always needing two rows - one 'Free' and one 'Other' - but if that is the case, you should be able to do a UNION query.

```
  SELECT StudentID, Location, Status, EconDisCode, StatusEffDate, EndDate
  FROM #TEMP_99RecordsNeedingEndDateUpdated 
  WHERE Status = 'Free'
  UNION
  SELECT StudentID, Location, Status, EconDisCode, StatusEffDate, (SELECT StatusEffDate-1 FROM #TEMP_99RecordsNeedingEndDateUpdated t2 WHERE Status = 'Free' AND t1.StudentID = t2.StudentID) AS EndDate
  FROM #TEMP_99RecordsNeedingEndDateUpdated t1 
  WHERE Status = 'Other'
```

I think a fiddle example with the data would be helpful.